# Error on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I am trying to run my Ruby application.

I am running the `bundle install` command, however get the error-

```
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.1.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that 'gem install libv8 -v '3.1.16.14.3' succeeds before bundling.
```

So then I tried-

```
gem install --version '=3.16.14.3' libv8
```

and get the error-

```
Error installing libv8: 
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

This is required to run the application however I am not sure how to resolve this?

Comment: You should check the rest of the error message after "Failed to build...", it will tell you why it can't build the extension or at least where to find more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
RUBYOPT=-rrubygems gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'
```

Comment: I did find this and tried to run it but it says 'RUBYOPT' is not recognised as a command?

Comment: have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126465/bundle-install-update-libv8-therubyracer-installation-fails-with-native-ex