# Bundle Install - libv8 installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, libv8

I have a rails app and when I run `bundle install` it gives me the following error:

```
SystemExit: exit
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot  continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3`, it installs without problems. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try running $ bundle exec bundle install

Comment: This [link][1] have the same issue i guess.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126465/bundle-install-update-libv8-therubyracer-installation-fails-with-native-ex/8127559#8127559